# Image does not appear in Relative Layout of Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, graphics, android-relativelayout

When inserting two images into Android Studio's Relative Layout, as shown in the photo below, you can see that images have been inserted into DrawableBottom, Foreground, and Icon:

[image]

But when running the same graphical interface on the mobile, the images do not appear. Please, what to do for the images to appear? It's in the Relative Layout of Android Studio.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your case I think should do this to show
`android:background:"@drawable/seta_direita"`

### Button:

```
<Button
       android:id="@+id/btn"
       android:layout_width="24dp"
       android:layout_height="24dp"
       android:background="@drawable/seta_direita"/>
```

RelativeLayout:

```
 <RelativeLayout
           android:id="@+id/layout"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:background="@drawable/seta_direita">
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

As you using just an image as background you should use ImageButton, not a regular Button.

```
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btnSetaDireita"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/seta_direita"/>
```